# Delphi / C++Builder 10.2.3 RESTRequest POST

Tags: c++, rest, delphi, post, c++builder

Does anyone have experience with `TRESTRequest` components? I am trying to `POST` a JSON string in the request body.

If I do not use `TOAuth2Authenticator`, it return back a `MISSING_CREDENTIALS` error.  When I try to use `TOAuth2Authenticator` linked to the `TRESTClient`, with an `access_token`, it gives me this error:

[image]

I did the same request with POSTMAN, it work fine. And also, it works fine with `TIdHTTP` as well.  But not with `TRESTRequest`.

Please let me know if you have experience before I report it as a bug.

Comment: By the way, I did use Bearer Token when TOAuth2Authenticator was not around.

Comment: Please show your actual code, sounds like maybe you are not populating the `TRESTRequest` correctly.

Comment: I found it... pls see the pictures below

Answer (score 2):

After some playing around, the answer should be as follows.

```
String StrBody="{\"Key\": \"A123\",\"Total\": 100.00,\"Deductions\": 100.00}";

SubmitAuthenticator->AccessToken = StrAccessToken;

SubmitRESTClient->BaseURL = "https://testsite.com";

SubmitRESTRequest->Method = Rest::Types::rmPOST;
SubmitRESTRequest->Params->Items[0]->Value = StrBody;
SubmitRESTRequest->Execute();
```

[image]